# how to extract string based on this manner in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to extract only these words if present in a cell:

{Beijing, New York, Japan}
I have a column with the following data(rowwise):
Nice city- Beijing, Awesome climate
Fair city- Japan, Cool weather
New York is so nice

All i want is another column which will have:
Beijing
Japan
New York

Is it possible to do it without vba?
Is there any formula? I have nth entries rowwise

Comment: (a) Since when is "Japan" a "city"? (b) What do you want if the cell contains "New York is not as friendly as Beijing"?

Comment: @YowE3K there are no such entries sir

Comment: @YowE3K all rows contain distinct cities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a formula such as

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("Beijing",A1),0)=0,"","Beijing")&
 IF(IFERROR(FIND("Japan",A1),0)=0,"","Japan")&
 IF(IFERROR(FIND("New York",A1),0)=0,"","New York")
```

Comment: if i put it in formula bar, will it work for a new column? Will my required stuff will get extracted?

Comment: @chaogao Yes and yes

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH({"Beijing","New York","Japan"},A1,1),{"Beijing","New York","Japan"})
```